# Specialize class instance in PureScript

Tags: purescript

Say I have the following type:

```
newtype T1 a = T1 a
```

I can make a `Show` instance for it:

```
instance showT1Generic :: Show a => Show (T1 a) where
  show (T1 a) = "generic: " <> show a
```

However, let's say I want to do something special for types `T1 Int`. I tried doing this:

```
instance showT1Int :: Show (T1 Int) where
  show (T1 a) = "int: " <> show a
```

and it compiles, however running in `psci` doesn't work as expected:

```
> T1 'a'
generic: 'a'

> T1 1
generic: 1
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining both those instances will raise an `OverlappingInstances` warning, for the reason you're finding here - it can make the instance that is chosen unpredictable.

I think if you flip the order of the instance definitions this will work, but it's not really recommended to ignore the `OverlappingInstances` warning.

You can't really do what you're trying to do here - you could alter the behaviour of an instance with a newtype, but specialising instances for some concrete types and having a generic fallback is always going to result in overlapping instances as it stands. Maybe if we introduce [instance chains](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/2315) this will become possible, but until then you're better off using monomorphic functions for this kind of thing.

Comment: This also breaks down in generic code: `f :: forall a. (Show a) => T1 a -> String; f = show` will never pick `Show (T1 Int)`. Parametricity prohibits special-casing types.

Comment: Thanks gb., I guess I did not see the warning because I was using psci exclusively.